Draw AdvancedMarkerElement on center of its position
I am drawing google.maps.markers.AdvancedMarkerElement's on a map.
I use them as handles/control points to change the path of a polyline.
They are drawn with a custom shape(basically a rectangle).
The issue is, that the marker is always above the position that it is bound to.
My code:
const parser = new DOMParser();
const pinSvg = parser.parseFromString(
        '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="16px" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="16px" fill="#000" " ><path d="M214-74q-59.12 0-99.56-40.44Q74-154.88 74-214v-532q0-59.13 40.44-99.56Q154.88-886 214-886h532q59.13 0 99.56 40.44Q886-805.13 886-746v532q0 59.12-40.44 99.56Q805.13-74 746-74H214Z"/></svg>'
,
        "image/svg+xml"
      ).documentElement;

 let marker =
        new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
          map: this.map as google.maps.Map,
          position: point.latLng,
          content: pinSvg,
          gmpDraggable: true,
          gmpClickable: true,
        });

The outcome:
Not properly centered AdvancedMarkerElement
As you can see the cross (added by google when hovering or grabbing the marker) is at the bottom of the marker. But I need the marker to be properly centered on top.
I tried changing the viewbox or x and y coordinates. Nothing helped.
It only distorted the shape.
Do you have any idea how I can fix this?

Warning : The SVG path you shared has syntax errors (one too many double quotes). Fix that first.
There are 2 options.
Option 1
You can use the transform function of the SVG itself. Your SVG being 16x16, you will need to translate the Y axis by 8 so that it appears vertically centered.
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" transform="translate(0 8)" fill="#000"><path d="M214-74q-59.12 0-99.56-40.44Q74-154.88 74-214v-532q0-59.13 40.44-99.56Q154.88-886 214-886h532q59.13 0 99.56 40.44Q886-805.13 886-746v532q0 59.12-40.44 99.56Q805.13-74 746-74H214Z"/></svg>

Here is a working demo :


async function initMap() {

  // Request needed libraries.
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
  const center = {
    lat: 0,
    lng: 0
  }
  
  const map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: center,
    zoom: 14,
    mapId: "4504f8b37365c3d0",
  });

  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const pinSvg = parser.parseFromString(
    '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" transform="translate(0 8)" fill="#000"><path d="M214-74q-59.12 0-99.56-40.44Q74-154.88 74-214v-532q0-59.13 40.44-99.56Q154.88-886 214-886h532q59.13 0 99.56 40.44Q886-805.13 886-746v532q0 59.12-40.44 99.56Q805.13-74 746-74H214Z"/></svg>', "image/svg+xml"
  ).documentElement;

  let marker = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map: map,
    position: center,
    content: pinSvg
  });

  let defaultMarker = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map: map,
    position: center
  });
}

initMap();
#map {
  height: 150px;
}
<div id="map"></div>

<!-- prettier-ignore -->
<script>(g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})
        ({key: "AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk", v: "weekly"});</script>



Option 2
Second option is to do the transform via CSS.
Use marker.content.style.transform = 'translateY(8px)'
or
marker.content.style.transform = 'translateY(50%)'
Here is the second working demo :


async function initMap() {

  // Request needed libraries.
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
  const center = {
    lat: 0,
    lng: 0
  }
  
  const map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: center,
    zoom: 14,
    mapId: "4504f8b37365c3d0",
  });

  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const pinSvg = parser.parseFromString(
    '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" fill="#000"><path d="M214-74q-59.12 0-99.56-40.44Q74-154.88 74-214v-532q0-59.13 40.44-99.56Q154.88-886 214-886h532q59.13 0 99.56 40.44Q886-805.13 886-746v532q0 59.12-40.44 99.56Q805.13-74 746-74H214Z"/></svg>', "image/svg+xml"
  ).documentElement;

  let marker = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map: map,
    position: center,
    content: pinSvg
  });
    
  marker.content.style.transform = 'translateY(50%)'

  let defaultMarker = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map: map,
    position: center
  });
}

initMap();
#map {
  height: 150px;
}
<div id="map"></div>

<!-- prettier-ignore -->
<script>(g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})
        ({key: "AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk", v: "weekly"});</script>




Thank you for the solution! This works well.
The only issue is that google draws a frame around the shape when it is in focus. (But it is not transformed, so it is misplaced)
Docs don't show any option to disable it.

Open a separate question with a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue.

I am sorry to say, but the minimal reproducible example is your code.

I don't see any frame around the marker, which is why I asked you provide a [mcve]. What browser are you using? etc.

Ok, I understand, i posted a new question and will try if the problem persists with another browser.
